# Curvature is invariant under change of orientation.

Tags: calculus

I am currently reading Do Carmo and am having trouble convincing myself of the following:

Let $\alpha(s)$ be a smooth curve parametrized by arc length, $\alpha:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $\beta(-s)=\alpha(s)$, (i.e. $\beta$ is the same curve but in the opposite direction.)

then $\frac{d\beta}{d(-s)}(-s)=-\frac{d\alpha}{ds}(s)$.

It seems like this might be using the chain rule but I don't see exactly why it works. How do I take the derivative with respect to $-s$?

Is it true that $-d(s)=d(-s)$? Why?

I have taken several analysis courses but am not used to these ideas being applied like this!

Comment: I find the notation $\frac{d\beta}{d(-s)}$ to be on the bad side. Better perhaps note $\beta(s) = \alpha(-s)$. Then $\beta$ is the composition of $\alpha$ with the function taking $s$ to $(-s)$ and you should be able to apply the chain rule to compute $\beta ' (s) = -\alpha ' (-s) $without issue.

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> Is it true that $-d(s)=d(-s)$? Why?

Use the
[Derivation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra))
on $\,-s=r\,$ to get $\,-D_t[s]=D_t[r]\,$ because $\,D_t\,$ is a linear operator.
Rewrite in terms of differentials to get $\,-d(s)=d(r)=d(-s).$

Answer (score 0):

When $ \alpha= - \beta,\; \Delta\beta$  is CCW, $\Delta\alpha $ is CW .. for sense of normal vector rotation in opposite directions in a widely followed accepted *convention*.

Curvature accordingly follows the same sign convention.

$$\kappa=\dfrac{d\beta}{ds}=-\dfrac{d\alpha}{ds}$$

$$-\kappa=\dfrac{d\beta}{-ds}=\dfrac{d\alpha}{ds}.$$

Curvature is not invariant under convention change!